# NSMutableSet addObject succeeds but disappear in next for loop?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I have a data structure showed below:

```
    -(void)renewTimeSpotArray{
        NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray new];
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            NSMutableArray *weekdayArray = [NSMutableArray new];
            for (int j = 0 ; j < 7; j++) {
                NSMutableSet *spot = [NSMutableSet new];
                [weekdayArray addObject:spot];
            }
            [tempArray addObject:[weekdayArray copy]];
        }
        _timeSpotArray = [tempArray copy];
    }
```

In other words, MyModel(Singleton) contains a timeSpotArray. The timeSpotArray contains 7 weekdayArray. Every weekdayArray contains 7 NSMutableSet. When I try to put something into these NSMutableSets from other Controller:

```
while ([s next]) {
            NSUInteger weekday = [s intForColumn:@"weekday"];
            NSArray *weekdayArray = [[[MyModel getSingleton] timeSpotArray] objectAtIndex:weekday];
            NSUInteger spotNumber = [s intForColumn:@"bigclass"];
            NSMutableSet *spotArray = [weekdayArray objectAtIndex:spotNumber];

            //MARK II
            DataModel *newModel = [DataModel new];
            //Configure newData ...
            [spotArray addObject:[newModel copy]];

            //MARK I
        }
```

At MARK I, I found newData was sucessfully added to one of the `NSMutableSet`. But when I check out at next loop, MARK II, there was nothing in any `NSMutableSet`!

What's the reason and how to solve the problem? I met this in ARC condition.

Comment: weekday in each while loop is changed so weekdayArray in current loop is difference than in previous loop

Comment: @ABáo But MyModel contains all of these Arrays. All change should affected MyModel, and when I get these Arrays, I should notice it's changed. Isn't it right?

Comment: All change should affected MyModel it's true. but MyModel->timeSpotArray contain a lot of difference weekdayArray. in previous loop you change previous weekdayArray, in current loop you check current weekdayArray. previous weekdayArray and current weekdayArray are still in MyModel

Comment: @ABáo How silly I am! Because problems of codes of display part, I just thought these data was not successfully stored in MyModel. Actually it was. I am just not so confident about my opinion on Memory-Management of Objective-C, thanks a lot.